# How to simulate time passing in angularjs test?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, timeout, jasmine

I am trying to pass a simulate time passing in an angularjs jasmine test.

My directive that I am testing simply displays the current time and updates every second:

```
return {
  restrict: 'A',
  scope: {
    format: '@'
  },
  link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

    var timeout;

    function updateElement() {
      if (scope.format) {
        element.text($filter('date')(new Date(), scope.format));
      }
    }

    function updateTime() {
      updateElement();
      timeout = $timeout(function () {
        updateTime();
      }, 1000);
    }

    element.bind('$destroy', function () {
      $timeout.cancel(timeout);
    });

    updateTime();
  }
};
```

In my test I need to simulate time passing. I tried with $timeout and $timeout.flush but I think I am using it wrong:

```
it('should update every second', function () {
  $scope.$digest();
  console.log('before: ' + element.text());
  var before = element.text();

  // Wait for a couple seconds...
  $timeout(function () {
    $scope.$digest();
    console.log('after: ' + element.text());
    expect(element.text()).not.toEqual(before);
  }, 5000);

  $timeout.flush(5000);
});
```

Should I use $timeout to simulate time passing by or is their another method to do so?

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/0V4AFGXqSfc9iLCuZbvn?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wrap the `$scope.$digest()` inside a `setTimeout` it should work. Like so:

```
setTimeout(function(){
  $timeout.flush();
  console.log('after: ' + element.text());
  expect(element.text()).not.toEqual(before);
}, 5000);
```

`$timeout.flush()` works in tests by just calling all the callbacks registered by `$timeout` regardless of their time value so you have to do the timeout outside of angular in this case. As you're only looking for a change every second your code would be calling `updateElement()` twice within one second.